# I heard that at quantum level the past-present-future is not in order, is this true? Is time really messed up there?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, time

I heard that, at the Quantum level, events can happen out of order making causality invalid. Thus the future can happen in the present and the present in the future. Is this true?

Comment: Where did you hear/read this?

Comment: I remember reading about this in the future.

Comment: [The Elegant Universe](http://say2.org/the-elegant-universe-strings-the-thing/01.htm)

Comment: Of all the classical things that quantum mechanics changes around or redefines or invalidates, quantum mechanics doesn't change the concept of time at all. Whoever said this may have in mind some dubious ideas about quantum gravity which have no experimental or sound theoretical foundation.

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0105101

Comment: Clock-time is the house-number of an event. Clock-time is defined by a thermodynamic mechanism. On some level of time resolution one has to wonder if quantum effects will make clocks unreliable, i.e. if one tries to read the clock too fast, will it break its monotonous counting cycle? The answer is probably positive for all conceivable clock mechanisms. Does that invalidate causality? I don't think it does, but it makes it necessary to redefine how we assign house numbers to events.

Answer (score 2):

In quantum field theory causality is preserved. See for example the answers to [In QFT, why does a vanishing commutator ensure causality?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/53148/in-qft-why-does-a-vanishing-commutator-ensure-causality). I'm afraid the subject is a bit technical, but I think it would be hard to give a popular science level explanation of how causality is preserved in QFT.

I don't know how causality is preserved in string theory, but the question [Causality in String Theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/30711/causality-in-string-theory) asks this very question and the reply indicates that causality is preserved.

So it is not true that causality is invalidated at the quantum level.