# How is causality encoded in string theory?

Tags: string-theory, causality

How is causality encoded in string theory?

There is a superficially similar thread, [Causality in String Theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/30711/causality-in-string-theory), which however asks a quite different question.

Comment: Just like it's encoded in the standard model: the theory respects Poincaré symmetry (the symmetry group of special relativity).

Comment: But Poincare symmetry is not enough for causality in quantum field theory. One needs local commutation rules for the fields. What is the equivalent of that in string theory?

Comment: You are aware of this thesis ? http://etheses.dur.ac.uk/3028/  ? ( way over my head :) )